# how to get the nodes which contain another xml nodes in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have few xml documents. and each document has different nodes. Only thing common is it has _Header and _Table nodes. what i want is to get the parent nodes which contain _Header and _Table nodes.

[image]

I want the program to output the following nodes:

```
_StatementofNetAssets_T1
_StatementofNetAssets_T2
_StatementofNetAssets_T3
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Some actual XML rather than a picture would be helpful - it looks like there will be namespaces involved which means the two answers provided probably won't work.

Comment: actual XML was too confusing, thats why i didnt add it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc=new XmlDocument(); 
string xmlname=Server.MapPath("*.xml").ToString();
xmlDoc.Load(xmlname); 
XmlNodeList    nodeList=xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("form/Documents").ChildNodes;//get all child nodes
foreach(XmlNode xn in nodeList) 
{ 
  XmlElement xe2=(XmlElement)xn;

  if(xe2.InnerText=="_Header"||xe2.InnerText=="_Table nodes")
  {
    XmlNode xn3=xn.ParentNode; 
    XmlElement xe=(XmlElement)xn3; 
    Console.WriteLine(xe.InnerText);
   }
}
```

Comment: I did as u asked, but there was a error in line 4.    "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in XmlToTable.exe
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: @ShalinkaRandeniya you should change`"form/Documents"`in the code  `XmlNodeList    nodeList=xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("form/Documents").ChildNodes` to be   the node name in your xml file.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `XDocument` class and [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp) to quickly parse your documents

```
var elements = XDocument.Load(path).XPathSelectElements("//_Header").Select(q => q.Parent);
```

You will be needing these namespaces

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;
```